# Форматирование кода в VS Code (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Как настроить форматирование кода в VS Code под C#
привык к нормальному компактному синтаксису в стиле Java, т.е.

```
void Start(){
     Sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;
  }
```

а VS предлагает так:

```
void Start()
{
    Sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению, в данный момент это не built-in фича, но проблема легко решается установкой стороннего расширения:

`Ctrl + P -> ext install csharpfixformat -> Install`

Форматирование: `Ctrl + Alt + I`

Конфигурационные строки описаны [тут](https://github.com/Leopotam/vscode-csharpfixformat#extension-settings) (по умолчанию установлен как раз Java стиль)

Comment: Отлично! то что нужно!!!! спасибо )) 
рейтинг не позволяет поставить плюс))

Answer (score 0):

Нужно зайти в меню: Сервис -> Параметры -> Текстовый редактор -> C# -> Форматирование -> Новые строки -> Расположить фигурную скобку на новой строке для методов (ну и для всего остального) и убрать галку

Comment: хм.... это в Visual Studio так настраивается) 
а мне бы в редакторе кода Visual Studio Code (VS Code)
тут вроде как немного по другому )))